# Problem with a program that converts a list of given number in a specific temp scale

Tags: python

I'm new to python and programming in general and I'm trying to make a program that takes as many values and convert that value in a specific choice of temperature scale. But I'm stuck and it keeps giving me a valueerror. If there's any other way making this program work, in for loop for example, i'm happy to learn! Thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
mylist = []
temp = int(input("How many temperature values do you want to take? "))
tuple(mylist)

def convert_temp(temp_scale, source_temp):
    if temp_scale == "F" or "f":
        return 'C', (source_temp - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
    elif temp_scale == "C" or "c":
        return 'F', (source_temp * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
        
temp_scale = input("Select F or C: ")
source_temp = int(input("What are the temperature? "))
s, m = convert_temp(temp_scale, source_temp)
print(source_temp, 'degrees', temp_scale.title(), 'is', m, 'degrees', s)
```

output:

```
How many temperature values do you want to take? 5
Select F or C: F
What are the temperature? 80, 90, 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\raini\mu_code\blank.py", line 12, in <module>
    source_temp = int(input("What are the temperature? "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '80, 90, 100'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me improving my own answer:

```
mylist = []
printed_temperatures = 0

def convert_temp(temp_scale, source_temp):
    if temp_scale == "F" or "f":
        return 'C', (source_temp - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
    elif temp_scale == "C" or "c":
        return 'F', (source_temp * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
    
temp_scale = input("Select F or C: ")
total_temperatures = int(input("How many temeratures do you want to give? "))
for i in range(total_temperatures):
    source_temp = int(input("What is the temperature? "))
    mylist.append(source_temp)
    s, m = convert_temp(temp_scale, source_temp)
    print(mylist[i], 'degrees', temp_scale.title(), 'is', m, 'degrees', s)
```

This will take an integer of total number of values as before and then will ask you about the temperature as many times as the value of total_temperatures and will convert them to f or c as per your choice.

Comment: Ahhh! Spot on! This is what i'm trying to achieve! Thanks a lot! I will try and modify this by having asking the user for input, store that in a list and then convert them from inside the list. Something like this,

` Select F or C : F
How many temp value? : 2
Enter temp value : 1
Enter temp value : 2
Temperature in Fahrenheit : [ x, x ] `

Comment: Btw, when I try to convert using this code from C to F it gives the same output as F to C.

Comment: I think it's working if we convert f to c but c to f isn't working. Let me debug this out

Comment: After thousands of checking, I got to see that in line no. 5 and 7, I have typed in `if temp_scale == "F" or == "f":` and `if temp_scale == "C" or == "c":` respectively. but the "or" operator won't work here cuz in python, after the "or" operator, you have to again put the condition without being respective to the previous one. Replace lines 5 and 7 with `if temp_scale == "F" or temp_scale == "f":` and `if temp_scale == "C" or temp_scale == "c":` respectively and then I am sure that it will work!

Answer (score 0):

`int()` expects to take a string that can be represented as a *single* integer, not multiple! The simplest way to handle your case in particular is probably with a loop:

```
temp_scale = input("Select F or C: ")
source_temp = int(input("What are the temperature? "))

# str.split() will convert a string into a list of substrings, 
# which were separated in the main string by the given character
# e.g. in this case, "80, 90, 100" -> ["80", " 90", " 100"]
for temp in source_temp.split(','):
    # will iterate once for every item in the thing we're iterating over
    # in this case, will iterate three times:
    #    temp = "80", temp = " 90", and temp = " 100"
    s, m = convert_temp(temp_scale, temp)
    print(temp, 'degrees', temp_scale.title(), 'is', m, 'degrees', s)
```

In this case, I opted to preserve the structure of your original code, and print a new line for every given temperature. You can experiment with, perhaps, putting the results `s` and `m` in their own lists, and then condensing the entire list into a single line of output somehow, after the loop is over.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in line no. 12, you are typing 80, 90, 100 and then converting that to an integer. As "," cannot be converted to int it gives a valueerror. There is no problem with the code.

You can try typing in one integer in the input "What are the temperatures? " in the terminal.

Or you can try this code too:

```
mylist = []
temp = int(input("How many temperature values do you want to take? "))
tuple(mylist)

def convert_temp(temp_scale, source_temp):
    if temp_scale == "F" or "f":
        return 'C', (source_temp - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
    elif temp_scale == "C" or "c":
        return 'F', (source_temp * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32
    
temp_scale = input("Select F or C: ")
total_temperatures = int(input("How many temeratures do you want to give? "))
for i in range(total_temperatures):
    source_temp = int(input("What is the temperature? "))
s, m = convert_temp(temp_scale, source_temp)
print(source_temp, 'degrees', temp_scale.title(), 'is', m, 'degrees', s)
```

I hope it worked!

Comment: Thanks! So this one works. But it only converts the last value I give it. There's something missing!

Comment: ok yeah wait I am giving you a renewed code as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

You are close just that you missed out on how to store all the numbers, since you can't convert a str of ints to a single int when gathering the values for `source_temp_input`.

```
temp = int(input("How many temperature values do you want to take?"))

def convert_temp(temp_scale, source_temp):
    # checking for both upper and lowercase is unnecessary
    # instead lowercase the temp_scale and check if its `f` 
    if temp_scale.lower() == "f":
        return "C", (source_temp - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
    elif temp_scale.lower() == "c":
        return "F", (source_temp * (9.0 / 5.0)) + 32

temp_scale = input("Select F or C:")
source_temp_input = input("What are the temperatures?")
# Use a list comprehension that splits the string by the comma 
# then you remove all the whitespace using strip() 
# finally you will need to convert them to int
source_temp = [int(temp.strip()) for temp in source_temp_input.split(",")]
# Now your `source_temp` is a list of ints which you loop over and
# convert the temperature 
for idx, temp in enumerate(source_temp):
    s, m = convert_temp(temp_scale, temp)
    # Use f"" string here instead of just printing the values
    # m:.2f just rounds off the value m to 2 decimal places
    print(f"{source_temp[idx]} degrees {temp_scale.title()} is {m:.2f} degrees {s}")
```

**Output:**

```
How many temperature values do you want to take?3
Select F or C:F
What are the temperatures?80, 90, 100
80 degrees F is 26.67 degrees C
90 degrees F is 32.22 degrees C
100 degrees F is 37.78 degrees C
                                                                                              
How many temperature values do you want to take?3
Select F or C:C
What are the temperatures?80, 90, 100
80 degrees C is 176.00 degrees F
90 degrees C is 194.00 degrees F
100 degrees C is 212.00 degrees F
```

Comment: I tried using your this, but it gives me an error on the output which is:

`File "<fstring>", line 1
    (m.2f)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @RainierEnriquez oops should be `{m:.2f}`, updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one worked. I'm curious as too how can I make it work without using enumerate? The actual plan was to add a certain amount of temp(numbers) from user and then add them to the immutable list then convert them to a certain choice of temp scale.

Comment: Ah an immutable list would be a tuple but you would still need to loop over them and print out the results. So I don't see how you would do it without the help of enumerate. Maybe you could use `map()` one for the `convert_temp` and another for the printing of the outputs but its unnecessary.

Comment: Ah it's also the same as your answer, but much more simple. Hahaha! But both very helpful. Different Ideas are good. I mean for my current knowledge, his code was easier to understand. But both are good input regardless.

Comment: But I saved in so I can learn it slowly while I dig deep with my studies, for sure.